# After updating android sdk getting error "Package name is not a valid java package name"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, package, admob

I want to update my app & my app package name contains "break" keyword, after updating my android sdk & including google play services lib to my unity project it gives me `INVALID PACKAGE NAME..` But when i remove `'google-play-services_lib' & admob jar` files from project, it wont give me error and project builds successfully...

I know "break" is a reserved keyword & cannot be used in package name but my problem is i want to update my app that already contains "break" keyword in package name..

2nd problem is that i also want to use `admob` in my game which uses google play services library.

I want to know how can i use `admob` & use same package name to update my app,
Any help/solution will be highly appriciated

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Comment: i am using unity3d tool, RESOURCE COMPILATION FAILED!

Comment: Package Name 'com.-----.-----.break' is not a valid java package name. See console for details